# Error when I try to install app-debug.apk generated by ionic4, on an mobile

Tags: ionic-framework, apk, ionic4, android-install-apk

I have already done all possible tests, deleted the 
`platforms/android`
 directory and re-generated, deleted the `node_modules`  and re-installed. But whenever I generate the apk to debug, the error continues.

The `ionic cordova build android --prod` command runs without any problem and generates the apk, as you can see below

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20m 9s
42 actionable tasks: 42 executed
Built the following apk(s):
        D:\life\Ionic Projects\myHealth\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

The problem is when I try to install the apk on real device, I get an error `App not installed`. See below:

[image: Imgur]

My ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\Sumburane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.9.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

My real device android version

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As strange as it sounds the problem is in the version of `Node.js` and `npm`, what I did was to download the new version of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and install it.
Next I updated the npm running: `npm install -g npm`.
Finally I deleted the `node_modules` directory and generated everything again:

```
npm install
ionic cordova build android
```

So now my `Node.js` and `npm` versions are:

```
NodeJS : v10.15.3
npm    : 6.9.0
```